# Make front- and backend (Angular 2 and Spring) Maven Multimodule Project

Tags: spring, maven, angular, spring-boot, angular-cli

How do I create a Maven multimodule project with a Spring backend and Angular2 front-end? Using spring initializr (https://start.spring.io) and angular cli separately seems to be straightforward, but how do I organize that as a multi-module Maven project with linked but separate pom-files? With what values and in what order should I create and initialize those? I can use Intellij IDEA if it makes things easier, but i am also fine with CMD (I'm on windows).

The only tutorial I found on this is here: https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/ but the guy uses some self-written "frontend-maven-plugin" which I do not want. Can someone explain the steps or link me to a tutorial that doesn't use third-party-resources but just clean Spring and Angular2, please?

> EDIT: when I posted this question, WebDevelopment was for the most part new to me. The below solution worked at the beginning, but for better scalability we decided to make separate projects later on: one FE project containing multiple Angular apps and many FE-libs (check out [NRWL's NX](https://github.com/nrwl/nx) for that). And one project for each BE-Microservice, each deployable separately in the CI-Pipelines. Google themselves go with the approach of one project for all the FEs and BEs, but they do have special requirements (all libs have to work with each other in the latest version) and they use the ABC-stack (Angular + Bazel + Closure) stack for that, which is not yet fully available for the public, but is worth keeping an eye on: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19058

Comment: Why don't you want to use the frontend-maven-plugin? It makes things easy, self-contained, and well integrated into Maven. It's perfect to integrate the angular cli build into the maven build.

Comment: I created empty project and added 2 modules - spring initializr and angular cli. Then i created my own scripts that built everything and copied angular app into resources/static/ directory. I guess there are better solutions, but it worked for me

Comment: @JBNizet because while this is cool to set up a hobby project, I do not want to use "some random" piece of code (even if it is under apache license)  later in a company project. Also I do not understand what exactly that plugin does - on the first sight I just see modules like FileDownloader etc - while it might be useful in the future, I would prefer keeping it minimalistic and adding needed modules later myself.

Comment: @msumera unfortunately I explicitly need a front-backend-multimodule maven project instead of a nested one, where the index.html and the angular-code is in the resources/static folder. my question is how I need to configure maven for that

Comment: Then write a plugin doing what you want by yourself. But beware, Maven, NodeJS, Java, Spring, Angular, TypeScript are all random pieces of open-source code. I won't answer on what this plugin does. It's explained in the README: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Comment: @JBNizet I have no problem with open source code. It is just that I want to keep the project minimalistic and add dependencies whenever I need to, instead of loading modules for things like grunt and bower which I am not sure if I will use in the future or not. This is my first time using Spring and I am just surprised that (according to your statement) you have to write a full-blown plugin just to make front- and backend code work with each other in one multimodule-project

Comment: @Phil Spring doesn't care about what you use on the frontend, and doesn't provide tools to build angular applications. This is best done by angular-cli, webpack, etc. So you just need something to integrate an angular-cli  build into a maven build. And that's the whole point of this plugin.

Comment: @JBNizet I understand that. I see at the end of the project only one single "mvn spring-boot:run" command is used, so apparently spring serves both, the back-end and the front-end, after it was transpiled to classic javascript (by node.js). But I want to work purely on the front-end while the backend is the responsibility of another team, so I want to separate the modules of the project and build the front-end separately (start up on localhost in development together though).

Comment: @JBNizet so this is (a part of) what this plugin is doing, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The recommended way to build an Angular 2 application is to make use of Angular CLI tool. Similarly when you work with Java EE projects you typically use Maven as the build tool.

To get the best of both worlds you can develop a multi module project as you already figured.

If you would like then just clone this sample:

git clone https://github.com/prashantpro/ng-jee.git

Given the frontend/UI project will be Angular 2 application.
Backend project can be Spring or purely Java EE application (Any web app).

We want to take the Angular 2 output (**dist** directory) and map it into the web application project for the UI part.

Here's how you can do it without any fancy third party plugins.
Lets take this Multi module project structure as an example:

**cd ng-jee** (This is your parent POM project)

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── ngdemo
│   ├── pom.xml    --- maven pom for angular module
│   ├── dist       --- This will be Angular output
│   ├── e2e
│   ├── karma.conf.js
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── protractor.conf.js
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── tslint.json
└── webdemo
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
```

The parent pom.xml needs to list both modules. The **first** module should be the UI (Angular 2) module followed by the Java/Spring module.

The important section is shown below for 
**ng-jee/pom.xml**

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>ngdemo</module>
    <module>webdemo</module>
</modules>
```

Next, if you have created your angular app using CLI like this:

ng new ngdemo

Then you need to place a pom.xml in that same directory **ngdemo/pom.xml**
Having the below build plugins: (This will build the Angular CLI project and generate output in its **dist** folder.

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>.</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>dist/**/*.*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>angular-cli build</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>.</workingDirectory>
                        <executable>ng</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>build</argument>
                            <argument>--prod</argument>
                            <argument>--base-href</argument>
                            <argument>"/ngdemo/"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The last piece of the puzzle is to reference this **ngdemo/dist** folder so we can copy the output into our WAR file.

So, here's what needs to be done in **webdemo/pom.xml**

```
<build> 
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>../ngdemo/dist/</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now, if you build the project from the parent directory **ng-jee**

`mvn clean install`

Then you will see that first it builds the Angular project then Web Project, while doing the build for the latter it also copies the Angular dist contents into the Web projects root.

So you get something like the below in the WAR/Web project target directory:

/ng-jee/webdemo/target/webdemo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

```
.
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── inline.d72284a6a83444350a39.bundle.js
├── main.e088c8ce83e51568eb21.bundle.js
├── META-INF
├── polyfills.f52c146b4f7d1751829e.bundle.js
├── styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css
├── vendor.fb5e0f38fc8dca20e0ec.bundle.js
└── WEB-INF
    └── classes
```

That's it. I will be doing a series on few of these aspects and more here [Angular and JEE](http://www.prashantp.org/blog/angular/2017/02/19/angular2-building-project.html)

Till then hope this helps!

Comment: Can I use this approach to add angular to an existing maven project with UI part?

Answer (score 0):

if the backend is spring framework based, it could leverage on the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`, which would serve static resources in configurable location, eg. /public, /static. Then the only need from maven is, package the front end submodule, with the configurable path as above (/public or /static for example) as the root level in the front end package/jar. The back end (Spring jar) as it is. Assuming the back end is with spring MVC (embedded tomcat for example), it would then route the traffic as: 1. for static resources to the front end package, 2. for the back end, route it to the back end package.

https://lwpro2.wordpress.com/2024/03/22/maven-multi-module-with-both-front-end-and-backend/