# How to add Node modules a Spring Boot project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, spring-boot, npm, webjars

I'm creating a web application with Spring backend and a React frontend. Its
configuration is based on this [minimal Spring Boot/React project](https://github.com/dpisarenko/minimal-react-boot-project).

Now I want to use the [react-checkbox-tree](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree) component in this project.

How can I do it?

I tried two different things.

**Attempt 1**

In the [pom.xml](https://github.com/dpisarenko/minimal-react-boot-project/blob/master/pom.xml) file the React module is included using the following declaration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
    <artifactId>react</artifactId>
    <version>15.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to find such artifact for the tree component, but couldn't.

**Attemp 2**

I tried to install the tree component as a global module (`npm install -g react-checkbox-tree`).

It didn't help. I get the error

```
[INFO] ERROR in ./src/main/js/app.js
[INFO] Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-checkbox-tree' in C:\myproject\src\main\js
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/js/app.js 5:25-55
```

during build.

**Update 1 (13.08.2017 23:57):**

On the [WebJars homepage](https://www.webjars.org/contributing) I found a
tutorial on how to package a Node module as a WebJar (so that it can be 
integrated into Spring Boot project like a normal Maven dependency). I started
to create the WebJar project for [react-checkbox-tree](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree).

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/dpisarenko/webjar-react-checkbox-tree).

Currently the problem is the `UPSTREAM_ZIP_URL` mentioned in the `pom.xml` in the
tutorial:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <upstream.url>UPSTREAM_ZIP_URL</upstream.url>
```

I looked at the code of the React WebJar and came to the conclusion that for
`react-checkbox-tree`, v. 0.6.4, `UPSTREAM_ZIP_URL` must be `https://unpkg.com/react-checkbox-tree@0.6.4/dist`. However, I don't find 
anything at this location. But there are some files at https://unpkg.com/react-checkbox-tree@0.6.4/.

I would appreciate, if someone answered the following questions:

1. Can I assume that in this case, `UPSTREAM_ZIP_URL` is equal to https://unpkg.com/react-checkbox-tree@0.6.4/lib/?
2. How can I build this web JAR project or submit it to WebJars.org?

Comment: I suggest, you split the application in two projects. One is genuine javascript , npm you name it based. You can configure webpack as you like it and generate a distribution that you version with maven. In your webapplication, you reference your frontend as a dependency and place it at the right position using wagon or dependency plugin.
This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532210/how-to-integrate-angular-2-java-maven-web-application

Comment: Thanks, but this solution sounds like last resort to me. I'm wondering how much effort it would be to package the tree package like the dependency from attempt 1 (i. e. make it possible to add the tree dependency via POM file).

Comment: There is another approach, they configure additional war resources from an angular project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593975/make-front-and-backend-angular-2-and-spring-maven-multimodule-project But they use a two project approach, too.

Comment: That "last resort" is the recommended approach. Separate backend from frontend, and only roll the frontend resources up into a dependency zip (jar).

Comment: If we compare the multi-project approach with packaging the dependency as a web JAR, why exactly is the multi-project approach better?

Comment: If you look at what happens with the webjar at https://github.com/dpisarenko/webjar-react-checkbox-tree/blob/master/pom.xml#L90-L105 you'll see that it actually unzips the jar. This is effectively the same as copying it from a sibling project, only without downloading from an external url. A multi-project in the same VCS has the advantage of keeping a change across frontend/backend in a single commit. I would also recommend the "last resort" :-)